# JPA - Join three tables. One with PK. The other two each have a part of the PK

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I have three entities:

**Customer**
It has a composite PK of... `customer_id` and `company_id`

**Data**
ID: data_id
FK: area_id (From Area below)
FK: customer_id (From Customer above)

**Area**
ID: area_id
FK: company_id (From Customer above)

How do I create the @Join annotations in JPA?  I assume I have to use @JoinTable, but I don't know how to do it.

**Customer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
@NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomerPK id;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to CustomColumnDataCustomer
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    private List<CustomColumnDataCustomer> customColumnDataCustomers;
```

**CustomerPK**

```
@Embeddable
public class CustomerPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="customer_id")
    private long customerId;

    @Column(name="company_id")
    private String companyId;
```

**CustomColumnDataCustomer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="custom_column_data_customer")
@NamedQuery(name="CustomColumnDataCustomer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM     CustomColumnDataCustomer c")
public class CustomColumnDataCustomer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="custom_column_data_cust_uid")
    private int customColumnDataCustUid;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AreaXCustomColumn
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="area_x_custom_column_uid")
    private AreaXCustomColumn areaXCustomColumn;
```

**AreaXCustomColumn**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="area_x_custom_column")
@NamedQuery(name="AreaXCustomColumn.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM AreaXCustomColumn a")
public class AreaXCustomColumn implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="area_x_custom_column_uid")
    private int areaXCustomColumnUid;

    @Column(name="company_id")
    private String companyId;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to CustomColumnDataCustomer
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="areaXCustomColumn")
    private List<CustomColumnDataCustomer> customColumnDataCustomers;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to CustomColumnDefinition
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="custom_column_definition_uid")
    private CustomColumnDefinition customColumnDefinition;
```

Comment: EDIT: The edit made it clear.
What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want a query to join them, or do you want to create a @JoinTable, or do you just want to find a way to make this relationship work in JPA?

Question is unclear to me

Comment: Did you write entities?

Comment: Looking for the relationship to work in JPA with the @Join annotations.  Yes I have made the entities.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this would be with the annotation `@EmbeddedId` and `@JoinColumn`.

I needed a similar solution on a project I did recently. I think it'll be easier if I explain it by example:

I have three objects, a `Platform`, an `EventMaster` and a `Membership`.

- The `Membership` is your Customer in this case, it has two PKs, the Platform ID and the EventMaster ID (this is solved by an `@EmbeddedID`):

  ```
  @EmbeddedId
  private MembershipKey id;
  ```
- The `MembershipKey` class simply consists of both PKs of the other class:

  ```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "eventmaster_id")
  private EventMaster eventMaster;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "mosplatform_id")
  private MOSPlatform platform;
  ```
- The `Platform` and the `EventMaster`class both look the same (this is in the `Platform`class):

  ```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.platform")
  private List<Membership> memberships;
  ```

I think that this should help you work out your solution.

EDIT: Code in the question was edited in.

Comment: ->  Does this allow you to join Platform and Eventmaster as well?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works for me.  Basically I want to join Customer and Data.  But one of the FK's (company_id) that I need in Data is in Area.  So instead, the FK of area_id is in Data, which then holds the second FK needed for the Composite Key of Customer.

Comment: I see, how are the classes linked? With that I mean OneToOne, OneToMany, etc.

Comment: I added the entities above.  This is based off a Legacy SQL database.  My thoughts are to not even join CustomColumnDataCustomer to Customer at all, and get the objects I need through a query

Comment: The objects you edited in above are already correctly linked, wasn't that the problem you had? In my opinion everything else should be done with a query. EDIT: With that I mean, all the @Join annotations you need for it to function, are already there.

Comment: You only need @JoinTable for a ManyToMany relationship, in this case I wouldn't use it.

Comment: With those types of joins, it wouldn't let me know CustomColumnDataCustomer to Customer, because it needed BOTH of the PK's from the Composite.  And I could only provide one from that Entity (customer_id).  company_id was within another Entity

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand what is not working. To get all the `Customer` based of the `CustomColumnDataCustomer`is possible. A query would be `SELECT ccdc.Customer FROM CustomColumnDataCustomer ccdc`.

Comment: But I see that you have to define JoinColumn first like so:    `@JoinColumn(
            name = "customer_id"
    )` on the `@ManyToOne`side.